# How to use the color hex code that is poured on the array in the linear-gradient?

Tags: reactjs, linear-gradients

I put the color hex code in the array and I want to use the name of the array inside it instead of using the color hex code in linear-gradient.(I use ReactJs Library)

#### colors.js

```
export const primaryGradient = ["#B16E2A", "#E9AD57"]//Gold
```

#### buttonH1.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { primaryGradient } from "../assets/colors";

const ButtonH1 = () => {
  return (
    <button
      type='submit'
      style={buttonStyle}
    >
      Submit
    </button>
  );
};

export default ButtonH1;

const buttonStyle = {
  width: 40;
  height: 25,
  backgroundImage: "linear-gradient(?)",
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) with es6.

So:    `` backgroundImage: `linear-gradient(${primaryGradient[0]}, ${primaryGradient[1]})`, ``